Find the point in a triangle such that the inscribed conic of the hexagon of incenters of triangles bounded by cevians and sides is circle?
$D$ is a point in the triangle $ABC$.
$AE,BF,CG$ are the cevians of $D$.
$H,I,J,K,L,M$ are the incenters of triangles $ADG,BDG,BDE,CDE,CDF,ADF$ respectively.
It is easy to see that $D$ is on $HK$, the angle bisector of $AE$ and $CG$.
So $D$ is the intersection of $HK,IL,MJ$.
By the converse of Brianchon's theorem, the hexagon $HIJKLM$ has an inscribed conic.
My question is, to find the point $D$ such that this conic is a circle.

My thought: This proof of Brianchon's theorem is particular to when this inscribed conic is a circle. Maybe we can use this proof to deduce some relations when this inscribed conic is a circle.

After some experimenting with GeoGebra, I suspect the locus of $D$ is just a single point (if any).

@Intelligentipauca Thanks, I have modified the question to a more appropriate title "Find the point ..."
